# Virtual C++ method with no polymorphism

Tags: c++, polymorphism, virtual, final, vtable

Suppose you have this simple class hierarchy:

```
struct base {

   virtual void f () const = 0;

};

struct derived : public base {

   virtual void f () const final
   {
      ...
   }   

};
```

There is only one implementation of f(), and because it is declared final, may we consider that there is no polymorphism ?

If so, will the compiler optimize code by avoiding use of a virtual table since 'You don't pay what you don't use ?'

Thank you.

Comment: Compilers are generally reluctant to change class layout during optimization, but the call itself indeed might be devirtualized. For *"[is] there no polymorphism [here]"*, you have to define what polymorphism is.

Comment: virtual functions and dynamic polymorphism go hand in hand. You can't rally have one without the other. There is a thing called static polymorphism which doesn't require virtual functions. (https://www.modernescpp.com/index.php/dynamic-and-static-polymorphism)

Comment: The compiler can't see into other compilation units.  These other compilation units may have derived other classes from `base`.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat I don't think it's possible to change the layout in this case, because having a single virtual function enables features like RTTI which require hidden class members.

Comment: @RichardCritten "The compiler can't see into other compilation units." - except that if you build with Link Time Optimization (LTO) then it actually *can* see into multiple compilation units and I know for a fact that (at least) GCC *will* devirtualize `final` classes/functions when it can.

Answer (score 3):

There is a polymorphism because there is a virtual function and you may define other derived classes from the base class.

From the C++ 17 Standard (13.3 Virtual functions)

> 1 [ Note: Virtual functions support dynamic binding and
> object-oriented programming. — end note ] **A class that declares or
> inherits a virtual function is called a polymorphic class.**

Answer (score 3):

> will the compiler optimize code by avoiding use of a virtual table

If the compiler has a `pDerived->f()` then yes, this is what it typically will do because this is what `final` is designed for in the first place.

If it has a `pBase->f()`, then such optimisation is only possible if the compiler can prove that `pBase` points to a `derived` and not any other class derived from `base`. `f` being or not being declared `final` is irrelevant for this analysis. Note that derived classes can come from different translation units. The compiler normally only sees one translation unit at a time, so it needs some kind of data flow analysis to eliminate this possibility. Link-time optimisations do not really help here because additional modules can be loaded at run time, and the link time optimiser cannot see them.

Answer (score 2):

I made an example in compiler explorer: https://godbolt.org/z/exsx8dzra

The code:

```
struct base {

virtual int f () const = 0;

};

struct derived : public base {

virtual int f () const final { return 2; }

};

int returnf(const base& b)
{
    return b.f();
}
```

The Assembly (x86-64 gcc12.2, -std=c++20 -O3) :

```
main:
 xor    eax,eax
 ret    
 cs nop WORD PTR [rax+rax*1+0x0]
 nop    DWORD PTR [rax]
returnf(base const&):
 mov    rax,QWORD PTR [rdi]
 mov    rax,QWORD PTR [rax]
 cmp    rax,0x401140
 jne    401138 <returnf(base const&)+0x18>
 mov    eax,0x2
 ret    
 nop    DWORD PTR [rax+0x0]
 jmp    rax
 nop    WORD PTR [rax+rax*1+0x0]
derived::f() const:
 mov    eax,0x2
 ret    
 cs nop WORD PTR [rax+rax*1+0x0]
```

Here you can see in the assembly that the virtual function call is not completely optimized away, namely there still is a check if the object is of the type derived:

```
 cmp    rax,0x401140
 jne    401138 <returnf(base const&)+0x18>
```

If so it returns the value specified in the method, otherwise it jumps to rax